# Serving sklearn model to AI Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, deployment, pickle, google-ai-platform

I am trying to serve a simple random forest model to AI platform!

I have saved it in google cloud storage as a pickle file using the following code

```
with open('model.pkl', 'wb') as model_file:
    pickle.dump(model, model_file)

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('bucket_name')
blob = bucket.blob("models/" + job_name + '/model.pkl')
blob.upload_from_filename('model.pkl')
```

The model gets saved fine in that location.

Why when i try to get it served in AI platform i get the error below? Any ideas? The error is not very specific, it only claims that **Error: model server never became ready. Please validate that your model file or container configuration are valid**. According to GCP documentation, pickle is a valid file type so i dont understand what I am getting wrong... Thanks in advance!!! :D

[image]

Comment: Were you able to solve this problem? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Is your model created using a custom container?
how did you create the model?
did you specify `--health-route=YOUR_HEALTH_ENDPOINT` and `--ports=PORT_WHERE_CONTAINER_LISTENS` ?